# Buildroot: Ncurses includes tput?

Tags: ncurses, buildroot, tput

I have a startup sh script that plays an "animation" of text, using tput to manipulate / delete lines on the terminal. Unfortunately it does not seem that tput is present on my system, I have included the ncurses library, which apparently also contains tput.

I am looking for either a way to get tput OR an alternative.

Thanks

Comment: The ncurses library *could* be present without any command-line utilities.  But fixing that is not a programming question, but instead a problem with packaging, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to enable `BR2_PACKAGE_NCURSES_TARGET_PROGS`.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have that enabled!

Answer (score 0):

You have to check **ncurses programs** when setup buildroot config

1. make menuconfig
2. Target packages -> Libraries -> Text and terminal handling -> ncurses -> ncurses programs
3. save
4. make clean (or rm -rf output/build/ncurses-6.1/)
5. make

After compile finish, you can find tput at output/target/usr/bin/**tput**

my buildroot version: buildroot-2021.02.3